# JSP file encoding in TomCat

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea, encoding, h2

I have use TomCat 8.00 and IntelliJ IDEA 14.0 and h2 database. When I get text from textfields in register form (cyrillic) records in the database are like this:[image]

It's importand to say that I made these configurations.
[image]

This is my **index.jsp** file

```
    <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

This is my **servlet**

```
public class RegisterServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String username = request.getParameter("usernameReg");
        String pass = request.getParameter("passReg");
        String name = request.getParameter("firstNameReg");
        String lastName = request.getParameter("lastNameReg");
        String email = request.getParameter("emailReg");

        request.setAttribute("Username", username);

        StudentBean regstudent;
        try {
            regstudent = new RegisterDAO().registerStudent(username, pass, name, lastName, email);
            request.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and my RegisterDAO class:

```
public class RegisterDAO {

    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement state = null;
    //ResultSet res = null;

    public StudentBean registerStudent(String userName, String pass, String name, String lastName, String email) throws SQLException{

        StudentBean result = null;
        String sql = "INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES(null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        try {
            conn = DbConnection.getInstance().getConnect();
            state = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            state.setString(1, userName);
            state.setString(2, pass);
            state.setString(3, name);
            state.setString(4, lastName);
            state.setString(5, email);
            state.execute();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Нулл поинт");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if(state != null){
                state.close();
            }
        }
       DbConnection.getInstance().Disconnect();

        return result;
    }
}
```

In English everything works fine. I think that jsp file is not corectly saved in UTF-8 and it still use default IntelliJ encoding.

I would be grateful for any ideas to resolve problem.

Best regards, 
D. Balamjiev

Comment: open your jsp file in intellij and check what you get in the bottom right corner, it should be the encoding of your file

Comment: It's UTF-8, but not working.

Comment: Check your database.

Comment: Far as I know H2 already supports Unicode, so you don't need to change the character set. Could you be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add this in your servlet.

> response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")